# c# GetManifestResourceNames() returns nothing

Tags: c#, localization, c#-2.0

I am using localization on my application and want to get a base list of `Resource` files that are used in the base language. Research shows that the following statement should get me what I want.

```
Assembly a = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string[] resNames = a.GetManifestResourceNames();
```

I do not get any errors, just an empty string array (`string[]`). I have tested this on both my local machine with IIS Express running and on my production server.

In looking at the `Assembly` variable locally, the value assigned is as follows.

```
 {App_Code.i5gd5jfv, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null}
```

Any help with this is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You code gets the resource names of the executing assembly. If your resources are in a different assembly, then getting the resource names of the executing assembly doesn't help. In other words: Your actual question is: How do I get the `Assembly` instance for the assembly that contains my resources, if it's not the executing assembly.

Comment: @dtb, I see. That makes sense. Back to the research.

Comment: @dtb, I have come up with a solution. It may not be pretty, but it works so far for me! Thanks for your input on this!

Answer (score 0):

Based on dtb's comment, I see that I was not referencing the `proper assembly`. So I have some up with the following code in order to get the proper `Assembly` for the `App_GlobalResources` and then get the list of resources.

```
Assembly[] assemblyList = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblyList)
{
    string assemblyName = assembly.GetName().Name.ToString().Split(new char[] { '.' })[0];

    if (assemblyName == "App_GlobalResources")
    {
        foreach (string s in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
        {
            //do stuff with the list of resources.
        }
    }
}
```

If there is a better way, please let me know!

Comment: Does the App_GlobalResource assembly contain any classes? Then the easiest way to get the `Assembly` instance is usually something like `typeof(SomeNamespace.SomeClass).Assembly`.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to figure out this out. It looks like it would be a lot cleaner and probably faster.